# Finding given sigma expressions with root denominator?

Tags: calculus, summation

The given sigma expression is $\\∑ _{n=0}^{120}\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\theta$
 I don't know how to find the sum of this given expression. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{(n+1)-n}=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$$
it follows
$$\sum_{n=0}^{120}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=(1-0)+(\sqrt{2}-1)+(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})+\ldots +(\sqrt{121}-\sqrt{120})=\sqrt{121}=11$$